# Can 2 lines that intersect result in a plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

If I have two lines that intersect what are the possible results of intersection.

For sure the result can be a single point, or a line(line intersects with itself).

My question: Is it possible that an intersection of 2 lines can result in a plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets of points that make up the lines will never form an entire plane. The intersection of two lines can either be no points (unique parallel lines), one point (non parallel), or one line (if the lines are not unique).

However, two unique intersecting lines will *denote a specific plane*. There is only one plane that contains the two lines.

In terms of vectors. Two non-parallel vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$ will span the plane.

Comment: If I have for line1 parallel vector $\vec v_1$ and for line2 parallel vector $\vec v_2$ then their cross product gives me the normal vector of the plane denoted by the 2 unique lines? Is what I am saying correct?

Comment: Yup. The cross product of two non parallel vectors $\mathbf{v_1} \times \mathbf{v_2} = \mathbf{n}$ where the result is in the normal direction to the plane as determined by the right hand rule.